# Traduction de « cookbook approach »

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cookbook

> cookbook adjective Definition of cookbook (Entry 2 of 2): involving
>   or using step-by-step procedures whose rationale is usually not
>   explained; a cookbook approach.

Comment s'interprète couramment *a cookbook approach* ? Je pense à *une recette magique* mais je me demande si je peux utiliser *(une) approche du livre de cuisine* ?

Comment: There are probably many context-relevant ways to express that in French... if only we knew the context...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pour une raison qui m’échappe, la langue anglaise voit davantage le livre de recette, qui applique une méthode de présentation standardisée, là où la langue française verra davantage le patron de présentation avec l’accumulation de recettes suivies. En français, la « recette de cuisine » sera davantage l’archétype du modèle d’explication que le livre les rassemblant.

Bien qu’il soit difficile de trouver des exemples l’attestant, je proposerais néanmoins ***« métode/mode/format recette de cuisine »***, qui serait clairement assez parlant pour moi : on laisse tomber le pourquoi et le flafla, on se contente d’expliquer le combien et une partie du comment.

Par exemple :

- Les solutions seront présentées ***à la manière recette de cuisine***.
- Un rapide survol de la méthode utilisée, ***en format recette de cuisine***.

---

<sub>On a parlé dans une autre réponse de ce qu’était et n’était pas la *« cookbook approach »* de la langue anglaise. On y a entre autre mentionné les tables d’intégrales, qui permettent de résoudre des intégrales en les brisant en morceaux, spécifiant que si cette méthodologie de résolution n’est pas traditionnellement appelée *cookbook approach* en mathématiques, rien n’empêcherait de le faire, car le concept est bien le même. Il est déplorable que quelqu’un ayant si mal cerné le concept anglais soit si péremptoire dans ses affirmations.</sub>

<sub>La résolution d’une intégrale faite en consultant des tables d’intégrales N’EST PAS la *cookbook approach*, car l’approche est celle de l’utilisateur, non celle du présentateur. La *cookbook approach* doit être celle de l’auteur, dans ce contexte celle du publicateur de la table d’intégrales, s’il a été décide de joindre une méthode d’utilisation à la table, montrant étape par étape comment résoudre une intégrale au moyen de la table.</sub>

<sub>De la même manière, une compagnie qui décide d’assembler des produits manufacturés plutôt que de réinventer la roue n’utilise pas une *cookbook approach*. Celle-ci surviendrait plutôt, potentiellement, au moment où la démarche d’assemblement est exposée aux travailleurs chargés de l’assemblement des pièces reçues :</sub>

- <sub>Retirer le sceau de la pièce A en veillant à ne pas endommager la rondelle de caoutchouc qu’il recouvre.</sub>
- <sub>Insérer la pièce B dans l’espace exposé de la pièce A.</sub>
- <sub>Visser un quart de tour, jusqu’à ce qu’un cliquetis se fasse sentir.</sub>
- <sub>Passer au suivant.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

*Procédure* est le mot qui me vient. Je laisse volontiers tomber *approche*: *approche procédurale* me paraît lourd. Si on veut insister sur le fait que l'exécution n'appelle pas de réflexion (ce que *procédure* suggère déjà un peu), on peut dire:

> appliquer la procédure *aveuglément*

Dans certains domaines où cette démarche est d'usage courant, on dit aussi:

> dérouler la procédure

Bien sûr, il y a aussi les anglicismes traditionnels:

- *Checklist* lorsqu'il ne s'agit que de vérifier un bon fonctionnement sans action particulière si tout est nominal,
- *Process*, quand *procédure* ne semble pas assez, heu... *corporate*.

Comment: L'idée de la _procédure_ c'est peut-être ça qui explique l'idée de _fondé sur des règles_ de certains acceptions techniques ? J'ai pensé transposer à partir d'un truc comme _paint-by-numbers_, mais bof, je sais pas si c'est vraiment utile ni si c'est vraiment proche de ce que veut dire _cookbook approach_ en anglais qu'au final je saisis plutôt mal. Merci !

Answer (score 2):

Étant dit que je m'accorde avec et vote pour la réponse apportée par Montée de lait et que j'ai pour ma part, utilisé à plusieurs reprises *recette de cuisine* dans des domaines très éloignés des petits oignons...

On notera dans certains métiers, (je pense à la médecine en particulier) l'existence du ***protocole***.

Un *protocole* c'est une suite d'actions, un enchaînement de traitements, examens observé par principe. Et conçu pour être suivi sans raisonnement, sans justification nécessaire, j'irai jusqu'à dire d'intelligence de la part de celui qui l'applique.

C'est je crois la qualité première d'une recette de cuisine. Pourquoi 5 oeufs ? pourquoi les battre ? pourquoi cuire au four ?

Parce que! Parce que c'est comme ça que ça marche! Toujours! Et que, par conséquent, même pour moi, ici et maintenant... ça va marcher.

*cookbook* porte (à mon sens) cette notion de garantie de bonne fin même pour moi qui n'y connais rien, voire, tout spécialement pour moi qui n'y connaît rien.

En ce sens, une autre expression que je rapprocherais volontiers est celle de **système D**.

Comment: @Montéedelait : Merci de m'avoir laissé le bénéfice du doute. C'est un vrai plaisir que d'écrire en sachant que ceux qui ont des yeux pour voir voient. D'ailleurs... *Montée de lait*... à votre sujet... je m'interroge... : *Je me demande si ce n'est pas **vous qui s**'appelle Sganarelle*... ;-)

Comment: **GrMBrGrrr de RonTIdJUU!!** Le comm auquel répond le comme ci-dessus vient de disparaître! Pfiuttt! évaporé!! Bon TammmmPI/2!

Answer (score -2):

On peut se faire une première idée de que « cook-book approach » signifie à partir de cet [exemple](https://www.doblin.com/our-thinking/innovation-a-cook-book-approach). Il n'est pas question de magique mais d'une façon de procéder qui est fondée sur un ou plusieurs recueils de directives qui ont été compilés dans le but de rassembler tout ce qui, dans un sujet donné, est ou a été utilisé, étudié, conçu, etc. On ne trouve pas d'équivalent français; les traductions dans [linguee](https://www.linguee.com/english-french/translation/cookbook+approach.html) ne me semblent pas satisfaisantes. Les termes tels que « miracle » et « magique » ne conviennent pas; 
Une chose à ne pas oublier est que le livre de cuisine figuré dont il est question n'est pas de la sorte que l'on imagine, avec une ou plusieurs recettes pour un problème donné; c'est le plus souvent un ouvrage ou un ensemble d'ouvrages qui contiennent des parties de recette que l'on combine pour résoudre un problème et dont le résultat sera dans l'absolu, unique en son genre. On en arrive donc à l'idée de réalisation sur un plan programmatique.
Un autre point de vue apparenté au précédent est celui-ci.
Comme il est question de résoudre un problème en identifiant ses divers aspects à des  aspects déjà considérés dans une philosophie du sujet, c'est à dire dans les recueils dont il est question ci-dessus, et d'assembler les éléments qui résultent de ces identifications pour obtenir le résultat particulier, ou en d'autre termes, comme il est question d'assembler des « modules », il me semble que l'on peut considérer l'idée sur le plan de la modularité.
En conclusion, une  traduction possible serait voisine de « **approche programmatique** » ou « **approche modulaire** » et possiblement selon le cas particulier, comme le terme « cook-book approach » est utilisé en de nombreuses circonstances, les deux termes eux-mêmes pourraient avoir leur utilité, chacun mettant en valeur un aspect particulier de la solution par « cook-book approach ».

Un terme avec le mérite d'être court et de rester dans le ton de l'original, bien que n'en préservant pas parfaitement l'idée, pourrait être « **approche catalogue** » (encore le résultat d'une idée personnelle, pas trouvé dans les parutions).

ADDITION

Quelques précisions supplémentaires permettront de se faire une meilleure idée du concept.

L'idée dans « cookbook approach » est que les divers éléments qui constituent la solution n'ont pas à être déterminés, ils sont tout préparés; il n'y a qu'à les identifier dans des ouvrages le plus souvent dédiés à la collection (catalogue)  et les assembler. Le principe ressemble au calcul des intégrales : on peut calculer une intégrale du début à sa fin en calculant chacune des intégrales intermédiaires soi-même; on peut aussi obtenir certaines de ces intégrales intermédiaires à partir d'une table, où elles sont toutes calculées (table d'intégrales)  et ainsi s'épargner beaucoup de travail. On ne dit pas dans ce cas que l'on a utilisé une approche « cookbook », ce n'est pas traditionnel en mathématiques, mais on pourrait.

Les situations qui impliquent une « cookbook approach » n'ont rien à voir avec la présentation de l'information et sont seulement des situations de recherche, de détermination de solutions; si ces situations sont telles que dans le domaine de recherche auquel elles appartiennent ont déjà été fournies beaucoup de solutions, au lieu de refaire un travail de recherche qui a déjà été fait, on va chercher les solutions dans les ouvrages qui les contiennent; le plus souvent on ne trouve pas une solution entière mais des morceaux, que l'ont assemble alors pour résoudre un nouveau problème dans le domaine donné.

*Un exemple typique d'« approche cookbook »*

Supposons qu'une firme, dont les besoins du moment sont un nouvel appareil électronique, ne juge pas nécessaire de faire la recherche pour développer les circuits individuels qui vont composer l'appareil, cela parce que ses ingénieurs savent qu'il existe des recueils de circuits déjà développés qui peuvent très bien faire l'affaire; on dit dans ce cas que la firme adopte une approche « cookbook » à son problème; ses ingénieurs identifieront les circuits voulus dans des recueils (catalogues) qui peuvent en contenir plusieurs milliers  et feront la recherche nécessaire seulement pour faire fonctionner ces circuits ensembles et aussi très possiblement pour leur fournir des composantes plus convenables ou plus modernes par exemple (résistances plus précises, nouveau transistors, nouveaux circuits intégrés, etc.).